# jQuery mouseup firing more than it should

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly, I am making a game as a little project (I have until tomorrow), the code is somewhat messy and is most likely causing my issues. It is still in its very early stages and is a work in progress.

Now, i tried using jsfiddle but does not seem to work when putting my little project in there, nevertheless, here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sMNpx/2/ and here is a link to the semi working thing: http://www.codehost.co.za/battleships/.

The problem I am having is after the first ship is placed. When trying to change the orientation, it changes and then changes again.

I assume it is on the mouseup event:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};

    $(document).mouseup(function(e1){
        if( e1.button == 2 && orientState == 1) {
            alert("ORIENTATION CHANGED")
            if(currentmouseevent == 1) //HORIZONTAL
            {
                $("#" + selectedship).css('width',selectedshipwidth + 'px').css('height',selectedshipheight + 'px');
                currentmouseevent = 2;
            }
            else if(currentmouseevent == 2) //VERTICAL
            {
                $("#" + selectedship).css('width',selectedshipheight + 'px').css('height',selectedshipwidth + 'px');
                currentmouseevent = 1;
            }
         }
         return true;
    });
```

I'm not particularly sure if the placement is incorrect.

Comment: You have to include jQuery library in your fiddle (top left)

Comment: Thanks, I have added it now. Still a little wonky, but at least it displays :)

Comment: 'selectBlock is not defined' please post the whole script in your fiddle. It has errors. Check console(F12).

Comment: Check you're not binding an event twice (or more) - for example binding a mouseup twice to a click event on the same div.

Comment: @shaunakde The select block is there, but it is commented out (towards the top), as it is a redundant function. Onclick now does nothing. Initially I was going to use it to select location. Thought it was to much effor and am now using keypresses and mouse functions to rotate and place 'ships'. Althought it is set on divs, it should not affect other functionality? Then again, I might be mistaken.

Comment: @logic-unit It shouldnt be bound to a div, it should be bound to the doucment. e1.button == 2 is only used once, hence my confusion.

Comment: Perhaps there is an issue with the conditions of the if statements? I have been sitting here for ages and cant figure it out.